# Any usage difference between two forms of indexing to array middle?

Tags: java, arrays

I saw that there are two ways to find the middle index in an array.

1. `int middle = lowerBound + (upperBound-lowerBound)/2`
2. `int middle = (lowerBound + upperBound)/2`

Are the same thing? Or they should be used differently? Since I am trying to understand binary search and merge sort. Both have to use it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this were simple algebra, the two expressions would be equivalent.  The complication is that `x/2` isn't the same kind of division you learned in algebra, because `/` is integer division, and if `x` is odd it will throw away the fractional part.  This makes a difference only if `upperBound - lowerBound` is odd.  So say it's odd, and specifically that it's `2N+1`, so that also `upperBound` = `lowerBound + 2N + 1`.  Then the first expression becomes

```
lowerBound + ((2N + 1) / 2)
```

which is the same as `lowerBound + N`, since the extra 1/2 gets thrown away.  The second one becomes

```
(lowerBound + (lowerBound + 2N + 1)) / 2
```

which is also the same as `lowerBound + N`; `lowerBound + lowerBound` and `2N` will both be even, so again the 1/2 gets thrown away.

So unless overflow occurs (see Rohit's answer), the two statements will yield the same result.

Comment: Good. it's always the same. So I would always use lower + (higher-lower)/2, which is safer, especially in interview!

Answer (score 9):

You should use the 1<sup>st</sup> one. The 2<sup>nd</sup> one might overflow, if the value of `lowerBound + upperBound` goes past the boundary values for that type.

Comment: can you clarify? when would (lowerBound+upperBound) / 2 ever be greater than the max bound? are you saying if the sum couldn't be held in an 'int' type for example?

Comment: @75inchpianist Yes. Exactly. For example, `lowerBound = 5`, and `upperBound = Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You wouldn't get the expected result.

Comment: @75inchpianist The program has to compute `lowerBound + upperBound` first.  If that can't be held in an `int` type, then the result of that addition will be a negative `int`.  Then it will still be negative when you divide by 2.

Comment: thats what i figured just making sure.

Comment: The usages are exact the same or different, without considering the overflow?

Comment: @user697911 The usage is same. They would give you the same result, when there is no overflow.